# Engine took a long time to warm up after putting chemical coolant flush in coolant reservoir

Tags: coolant, radiator, temperature, thermostat, flush

I have a 2006 Kia Rio 1.6L. Yesterday I put in chemical flush in the coolant reservoir since I’m flushing the system out on the weekend. I drove it once yesterday and the temperature increased as normal. Today when I drove it, the temperature was still at C after about 5 minutes, after about 20 minutes of driving, the engine finally got up to near normal operation temperature. What could the cause of this be?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that can cause slow warm up is a stuck open or missing thermostat. Change the thermostat and all will be well.